# laravel two table value compare , and show value in foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

laravel compare two table value and show the value in foreach. my code showing error help me to solve  this.

i am comparing  "delete_status" in both model if  "supplier" model delete_status is  "NOT_DELETED" it compere titem_list model "delete_status" values if "NOT_DELETED" it will showed items in foreach other showed dont show item.

my controller

```
public function  totalproduct()
{
    $totalproductlist = DB::table('item_lists')->join('suppliers', 'item_lists.delete_status', '=', 'suppliers.delete_status')->where('suppliers.delete_status','=','NOT_DELETED')->get();
    return view('suppliers.total-product',compact('totalproductlist'));        

}
```

my model (  Item_list )

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item_list extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'item_lists';
     protected $fillable = ['product_name','qty','purchase_rate','MRP_rate','sale_rate','supplier_name','part_no'];

}
```

my model (  Supplier )

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Purchase;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Supplier extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'suppliers';
     protected $fillable = ['party_id','suppliers_master_id','suppliers_unic_id','supplier_name','email','phone','address','city','state','pincode','GSTIN','delete_status','BILL_TYPE'];

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item_list::class, 'supplier_name', 'supplier_name');
    }
}
```

Comment: @sta check my controller code i tried to show value of only "NOT_DELETED " items  but it showing all value. i dont want to show "DELETED" status values

Answer (score 0):

You are telling SQL to select the models with `DELETED` status:

```php
$totalproductlist = DB::table('item_lists')
  ->join('suppliers', 'item_lists.delete_status', '!=', 'suppliers.delete_status')
  ->where('suppliers.delete_status','=','DELETED')->get();
                                         ^^^^^^^
```

Changing it to only select `NOT_DELETED` is as simple as changing the string:

```php
$totalproductlist = DB::table('item_lists')
  ->join('suppliers', 'item_lists.delete_status', '!=', 'suppliers.delete_status')
  ->where('suppliers.delete_status','=','NOT_DELETED')->get();
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: not working check my controller code i tried to show value of only "NOT_DELETED " items but it showing all value. i dont want to show "DELETED" status values

Comment: That's what it's written in the answer, have you at least read both snippets?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined two model, which is basically for [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent). But you are using [laravel-query-builder](/questions/tagged/laravel-query-builder), not [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent). You can use **[whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties) eloquent** method, like this :

```
$q = Supplier::whereHas("items", function ($query) {
        $query->where("delete_status", "NOT_DELETED");
   })
   ->where("delete_status", "NOT_DELETED")
   ->get();
```

Comment: Must add `use App\Item_list;`  on the top, to call the Model Class

Comment: Call to undefined method App\Item_list::suppliers()

Comment: I misspelled, try again.

Comment: Add `use App\Supplier;` on the top

Comment: @user12931578 would you clrify more, what you got what you expected?